# Placing a Logo over the Quick Launch left nav on Seattle Masterpage SP 2013

Tags: 2013, master-page, navigation, site-logo

I'm trying to add a logo over the Quick Launch Left Nav.
I am pretty much using the Seattle Masterpage.

I tried using SharePoint Designer with `Seattle.html` but I just can't figure out where to slip the image source to fir over the Left Nav.

In SPD 2013, without the design tab, I'm blind. I don't where to add the image code there either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the OTB Seatle.html master page then the sideNavBox area starts at line number 294.

```
<div id="sideNavBox" role="navigation" class="ms-dialogHidden ms-forceWrap ms-noList">
```

You could place DIV with the logo inside it and play round with the placement within all the components, i.e  all represent chunks of code when rendered in the browser.

Comment: Hello Steven , so far so good BUT it pushes all the content on the right of the quick launch down. Is there a way to have that logo there without that happening? And thank you!

Comment: I'd need to see outcome in the browser...do you have a screen grab?

Comment: You rock. I just left the dub part out and placed the image on top of the sideNavBox code. Thank you!

Comment: Mark up as the answer then ;-)

Comment: New here. How do I do that please?

Comment: There should be a tick Icon/Button next to this post...